# Similar, but different

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Try figure out the answer to this puzzle. The answer is 13 letters in total.

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> **CELESTIAL BODY**

How do we arrive at this? First interpret the rebuses at the top - these signify (from top to bottom):

> **NO [OM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om)**
>  **TEN [ALP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alps)(S)**
>  **RATS**
>
>  And if we make use of the backwards-pointing arrow to imply *reversing* these words, we get: **MOON**, **PLANET** and **STAR**...

Next turn your attention to the bottom image, resembling three circles of different sizes...

> If we interpret these to be representing a moon, planet and star then (ordinarily) the smallest would represent the moon, the medium-sized one the planet, and the largest the star.
>
>  To read off the hidden key phrase we need to spell out specific words among the boxed letters and then read off the corresponding letters from just outside the boxes. But what words do we need to spell out...?
>
>  Well, among the letters we can spell out thematic words which are the traditional names of our own moon, planet and star (in Latin)! In other words: **[LUNA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Luna)**, **[TELLUS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tellus)** and **[SOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol_(Roman_mythology))**
>
>  If we trace these out within their respectively-sized circles of boxes, we spell out the letter sequences: **CELE**, **STIALB** and **ODY**, or - with spacing corrected - **CELESTIAL BODY**, which is what moons, planets and stars are (albeit - as per the title - whilst being very different from each other at the same time)!
>
>  [image: Spelling out the answer in the image]

Comment: All good. Well done 